# Background music not playing in Ios Device

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am developing an Application in Xcode using cocos2d-x. In my application i am having background music and effects. While I tried it with Android device the background music and effects are playing perfectly, and it is also playing in Xcode simulator but when I tried my application with ios device, background music is not playing, But all other sound effects are playing which are occurs through events.Even I tried to play background music while event occurs, but its not working. Anyone please help me to solve this. I am using the following codes for playing background music and effects.

```
    CocosDenshion :: SimpleAudioEngine :: sharedEngine () -> playBackgroundMusic ("gamemusic.mp3", true);

    CocosDenshion :: SimpleAudioEngine :: sharedEngine () -> playEffect ("Hello.mp3");
```

Comment: have you included #include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

Comment: have you tried it using wav files?

Comment: Yes, I included SimpleAudioEngine.h",

Comment: No, I didn't try with wav file. But my application is working well in all android devices

Comment: in the notes it says it recommends .caf files for ios

Comment: suggest http://media.io/

Comment: or mport audio files to iTune
in iTune preferences, Advanced->Importing->Import using: AIFF Encoder.
right click on the audio files -> Convert Selection to AIFF
right click on the newly created files -> Show in Finder 
rename the file from .aif to .caf

Comment: I tried with .caf file also but still it's not working.Anyway effects are playing even it is in .mp3 format.

Comment: is your music file included in your app target ?

Comment: its not .mp3 versus .caf issue. .mps is fine in cocos2d-x. I'd make sure that the .mp3 are in your Resources directory and that you are including them in with your target.